# Static Website: I want to host different subdomain (=different directory) on github service?

Tags: github, subdomain, github-pages

Github allows you to host your static website for free. On [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages), Github describes the difference between **User Pages** and **Project Pages**. I can't understand the difference!

Currently, my website is running on github well. but I want to add a sub-domain to it.

**www.123.github.io** -> redirects to *123.com* (which is a repository on Github, too.)
**www.123.com** -> is working
**www.blog.123.com** -> how? -> should it be "*Project pages*"?

I mean, can I run a domain and a subdomain in one repository?
In summary:

1. Can I host a domain and a subdomain using [Github-Pages](http://pages.github.com/)?
2. Can I host different subdomains (*a.123.com*, *b.123.com*, ....) on github? Is it possible into one repository? (according to the Github limitations, the repository name should be the same as Github username, so we can just create just one repository under each account!)

Comment: Webhosting with GitHub questions are off-topic

Comment: @random - do you mean all [github-pages] questions are offtopic by definition?! If you mean hosting generic sites is off-topic but a programming-specific "can I host documentation for multiple libraries?" would be OK, I disagree - forcing OP to explain which kind of sites to establish on-topicness would just spam the question with irrelevant detail.

Comment: About hosting sites is off topic. Just as asking how to setup a domain for hosting, like on Tumblr, WordPress, GitHub, Launchpad, etc. Webmasters SE if anything. "Can I host..." would also be off topic. @ben

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that each repo can have its own Project Page (from `gh-pages` branch) but you can have only one User page—in a specially named repo.
However you can also create multiple Organizations from a single user; Org Pages are similar in spirit to user Pages.

Project pages are served in subdirectories of the same domain (`username.github.io/projectname`), but each can have its own custom domain if you [add a `CNAME` file (and arrange DNS)](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages)).

In any case, you at most get one domain per repo.

You can use `a.123.com` and `b.123.com` for different repos but I'm not sure if you can get it simultaneously with `123.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GitHub doesn't allow multiple subdomains in a single repository, so you'd need to have two repos pointing to the two different URLs.

Comment: According ti Github-Help: "The repository must use the username.github.io naming scheme.", which means just one repository is available! @James, 2 repos means 2 account! Is there any else service with the ~same facility? (=free hosting for static website via git?)